# Set outerWidth in percentage using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, css-float

### Short version

My code works well if I don't set horizontal margin. This is why my code use .width() for get and set an element width, but I can't do the same with .outerWidth() because it's read-only. Is there a way to set it?

### Long version

I've many buttons (using `float: left`) with various widths and I want to have a single width for every of them, in order to make a nice and optimized button table.

So I've written this:

```
buttons = $('.button-table > button');
maxWidth = Math.max.apply(
    Math,
    buttons.map(function(){
    return $(this).width();
    }).get()
);
columns = Math.floor($('#container').width()/maxWidth);
buttons.width(100/columns+'%');
```

This code works, but if I set an horizontal margin for the buttons, the last ones shift on the next lines.

Note: I prefer percentages because if I use this code I often see some pixels left at the right end of the container (I can see them using a different color):

```
buttons.width(Math.floor($('.button-table').width()/columns));
```

**Note**

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, so excuse me if I make mistakes using this platform.

Comment: Where do you put the horizontal padding in e.g. `#container` or `button`?

Comment: @Rezigned Sorry, I meant margin, not padding (I just fixed my question). I use it for `button`

Comment: @MalSu Sure: http://jsfiddle.net/x33bD/2/ (I don't know why my Firefox nightly build sometimes there's some space left on the right - Just press F5 if it occurs)

Comment: I'm very sorry, man. I still can't grasp your problem.

Comment: Thank you for having tried to help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution:

No margin: http://jsfiddle.net/x33bD/2/

With margin: http://jsfiddle.net/x33bD/7/

Basically, I've added divs (using `class="box"`) around buttons with this style:

```
.box {
    float: left;
}
.box button {
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This CSS could be better: it could stretch the buttons without setting the width.

The jQuery code is the same (`buttons` becames `.box`, .width() becames .outerWidth()...):

```
boxes = $('#container > .box');
maxWidth = Math.max.apply(
Math, boxes.map(function() {
    return $(this).outerWidth();
}).get());
columns = Math.floor($('#container').width() / maxWidth);
boxes.width(100 / columns + '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly. You would like to set the `width` + `margin` for those buttons.

Here we go.

As you might already know. `total width` = `margin` + `border` + `padding` + `content width`

So, in your case you can just do this.

```
var buttons = $('.button-table > button'),
// filter out the widest element
    widest  = buttons.sort(function(a, b){ return $(a).outerWidth() - $(b).outerWidth(); }).pop(),
    btn_width   = Math.floor($('.button-table').width()/columns),
    btn_margin  = parseInt($(widest).css('margin-left')) + parseInt($(widest).css('margin-right'));

// set actual width
button.css({
    width: btn_width - btn_margin
})​
```

Comment: @FrancescoFrassinelli I've tested with your http://jsfiddle.net/x33bD/2/ (replace your js part with mine and add the margin to button). it works fine for me. or maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: Ok, here's the problem: in your code there's no definition for columns and the buttons don't use the whole #container width (as my jsfiddle does - try to move the vertical bar).